# long numbers to date/time conversion or logic?

Tags: java, android, numbers

i have an xml file which is representing time in a numbers format, for example

**1361988590126** is representing date/time **27/02/2013 19:09**

from searching i have been able to understand that this date/time is being converted to milliseconds using some java / javascript code consisting of 13 numbers.

i needed to know how this logic is working and how will I be able to interpret these numbers to convert them to time and vice versa.

and if someone can please give me some formulation of how this time is being converted to decimal as started from that standard Yr. 1970

please help.

Thanks

Comment: which programming language are you using?

Comment: @Mr_Green it is an android based app which decompile to learn the basic understanding of android OS. well.. i am sure that the programmer has used java as its programming language, please see below a snippet from code. `iput-object v0, p0, Lcom/user/dire/Conversation;->mSelected:Ljava/lang/Boolean;`

Comment: you should mention everything related to your question. otherwise, no one can understand what you are asking. read this http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, have a look here: [http://xkcd.com/1179/](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/MillisecondToDate.shtml) :)

As far as I know, it is just a counting of miliseconds since 01.01.1970
and the Date-object has an constructor, that knows how to handle it.
You should be able to convert back and forth using the proper `SimpeDateFormat`.

```
public class MillisecondToDate {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        long yourmilliseconds = 1119193190;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");

        Date resultdate = new Date(yourmilliseconds);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(resultdate));  
    } 
}
```

examples can easily be found via google, like http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/MillisecondToDate.shtml
and http://www.java-examples.com/convert-date-milliseconds-example

Comment: thanks. your references and codes have been of a great help :D